# Multivariable cox regresssion - comparison of definitions

Tags: multiple-regression, survival, cox-model

I am currently doing a data-analysis where I want to evaluate the use of a new definition. If patients adhere to this definition they are diagnosed with RAR. The criteria of this definition are being female; hormonal level above cut-off and hCRP above cut-off.

I want to analyse if adhering to the RAR definition impact overall survival and increases the risk on heart failure.

STEP ONE
Therefore I would do the following multivariate cox regression analysis including:  RAR, age, smoking history -> each providing me with a Hazard ratio and p-value.

STEP TWO Then I would repeat the analysis to see what the impact of individual components of the RAR definition had. In this model, I would include female, hormonal level above cut-off, hCRP above cut-off, age and smoking.

I would want to do both steps to see if the new definition has added value or if it would be better to still use the individual components as risk factors.

Is this approach correct in use or is it incorrect to rerun the same model?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Those cutoffs don't exist in nature, and any attempt to create cutoffs out of continuous relationships is doomed to failure, in particular making the model have poor fit and poor predictive discrimination.  Model continuous hormone levels, and try not to assume linearity in the log relative hazard, e.g., use regression splines.  Then assess the added value of each lab measurement using multiple degree of freedom measures as in [here](https://fharrell.com/post/addvalue).

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately, I can not use a logistic approach since patients follow-up is very different between the patients. But if I would change to continuous levels in my set-up and could I use the model since I do not wish to look what is the best predictor or what predictor we should use in clinical practice. Just, if the RAR is better or worse at predicting than it's individual components.

Comment: You misunderstood my comments.  Keep the follow-up time continuous but use the continuous form of all predictor variables.   The predictor thresholds are invalid and will result in a poor fit.